# In Django, ModelAdmin, what is the difference between save_form() and save_formset()?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, overriding

Can somebody explain the differences and/or similarities between save_form and save_formset from ModelAdmin?

The only things i could find about this is from source code.

```
def save_form(self, request, form, change):
        """
        Given a ModelForm return an unsaved instance. ``change`` is True if
        the object is being changed, and False if it's being added.
        """
        return form.save(commit=False)


def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        """
        Given an inline formset save it to the database.
        """
        formset.save()
```

And the docs have only this about save_formset (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_formset)

> The save_formset method is given the HttpRequest, the parent ModelForm
> instance and a boolean value based on whether it is adding or changing
> the parent object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/formsets/) is a bunch of equal forms.  For example if you have a form where a user enters a food he likes, but then you want the user to be able to keep adding more, as many as he wants, then the formset will generate forms with an input for food, and will generate new, blank inputs, as the list grows.  When `formset.save()` is called, all those forms are saved, and that is what save_formset() is doing.

As shown in the example in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_formset), you can override this, for example to add a user to each form in the formset before committing the changes to the database:

```py
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for obj in formset.deleted_objects:
            obj.delete()
        for instance in instances:
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
        formset.save_m2m()
```

Now, `save_form()`, is just to save a regular form, but as you can see it has `commit=False`, so the form is not saved to the database yet.  Data can be added to the form until it is ready to be committed to the database.  If the form is based on a model with a `ManyToManyField`, that field cannot be saved until the model instance is first saved, so this is where `form.save_m2m()` in the following function in the same [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/options.py):

```py
def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        """
        Given the ``HttpRequest``, the parent ``ModelForm`` instance, the
        list of inline formsets and a boolean value based on whether the
        parent is being added or changed, save the related objects to the
        database. Note that at this point save_form() and save_model() have
        already been called.
        """
        form.save_m2m()
        for formset in formsets:
            self.save_formset(request, form, formset, change=change)
```

**Note**
I'm relatively new to formsets, and have never myself modified or used [ModelAdmin methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods), so if anyone sees anything wrong with my summary, let me know.